# How to compact elements of a string in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm in need of some help. I have a program who stores elements in a string, something like this:

> `"D,C,D,C,D,C,C,C,D,C,C,D,C"`

And I want to compact those elements and print them to the sreen like this:

> `(DC)3C(CDC)2`

Where (DC)3 means the program had compact the string "DCDCDC", meaning DC would be repeated 3 times and knowing that each group of elements inside the () can only have 3 elemens max.

So far I had compact only elements of the same type as

> `"DDDCDCC"`

into:

> `D3CDC2`

Any help will be gladly appreciated.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://lazarenko.me/ask-smart-questions-and-you-will-succeed/)

Comment: Please try to explain how you get from snippet one to snippet two. it doesn't have to be in code, but right now, you're showing things like '3C' and '2' which are not contained in the original string. Where do these numbers com from?

Comment: @evanmcdonnal i think it's (pattern1)x3, C, (pattern2)x2

Comment: I think he might be attempting to perform a rudimentary form of run-legnth-encoding.

Comment: @AK4749 yes, a poor mans regex.

Comment: do you care if it is absolutely the best solution? because finding a simple sub-optomal solution would be easier than exhaustively testing for the very best solution... considering consuming part of source material may shorten a subsequent pattern that could be made...

Comment: @Grady Player for now i'm only interested in a solution, because this function is part of a larger program and only in the final stage should we care about the best solutions.

Comment: What is the logic behind this grouping? There are multiple solutions for your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's explore what you're trying to do with an easier task.  Collapse any instances of `DC` or `CDC` in the following string:

```
[D,C,D,C,D,C,C,C,D,C,C,D,C]
```

Since `DC` appears in `CDC`, we should do the longer string first.  Starting with the first character, see where you find the pattern `CDC` starting:

```
DCDCDCCCDCCDC
 ^     ^  ^
```

Collapsing each of these results in:

```
D(CDCx1)DCC(CDCx2)
```

Now, check for `DC`:

```
D(CDCx1)(DCx1)C(CDCx2)
```

Uh-oh! This didn't result in your example output! What if we do the search in the other order?  Marking each `DC` results in:

```
DCDCDCCCDCCDC
^ ^ ^   ^  ^
```

Which collapses into:

```
(DCx3)CC(DCx1)C(DCx1)
```

Huh, that doesn't result in your output either.

So, which happens if we try a different tactic... let's start at the beginning and greedily match any pattern as soon as we can:

```
DCDCDCCCDCCDC
^
```

Can we match CDC? No. How about DC? Yes!

```
(DCx1)DCDCCCDCCDC
      ^
```

Starting after the first replacement, we do the same test. CDC? No. DC? Yes!

```
(DCx2)DCCCDCCDC
      ^
```

Once more: CDC? No. DC? Yes!

```
(DCx3)CCDCCDC
      ^
```

CDC? No. DC? No.  Skip to the next character.

```
(DCx3)CCDCCDC
       ^
```

CDC? Yes!

```
(DCx3)C(CDCx1)CDC
              ^
```

CDC? Yes!

```
(DCx3)C(CDCx2)
              ^
```

We've reached the end of the text, and what's more, the output matches the expected value. So, to extend this to the full algorithm you'll need the complete list of possible subsets: CCC, CCD, CDC, CDD, DCC, DCD, DDC, DDD, CC, CD, etc.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @Bill, that might help, i'll have to cover all the possibilities but it'll bring the right solution. Thanks mate for the understanding.